# Animation For Save functionality wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm working on wpf application in which when i click on save button then a pop up will display with "OK" and "Cancel"and when i click on Ok button then Glass Hour will appear for few seconds and  "Save Successfull..." message will be displayed at the top for 1 or 2 seconds and then it will be dissappear ,and when we click again on save button again "Save Successfull.." message will be displayed....plzz share somme suggesions.

right now i'm working like this

```
<Label x:Name="lblSave" Content="{Binding LblContent}" Margin="500,80,0,0" FontSize="20" 
        Visibility="{Binding LblSaveVisibility}">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard >
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>

                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Comment: Consider using a timer (dispatcher)